# How to C# WinForm datatable loop through rows and columns to datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Sql query return

```
cid   Sid  SalesName  Ratio  Price   Amount

1    01   Mike        11      80      120
1    11   Salier      10      70       90
3    04   Amy          8      60      200
3    01   Mike        25      110     600
```

I would like it displayed as follows on datagridview or sql query

```
cid   Mike_Price Mike_Amount Balance  Salier_Price  Salier_Amount Balance Amy_Price   Amy_Amount
1         80        120         40        70               90       20      0            0
3        110        600         490       0                0        0      60          200
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display what you want, you have to write query which returns your second statement. From your table it seems it is impossible.

Comment: i want to fill datagridview like Second code

cid   Mike_Price Mike_Amount Balance  Salier_Price  Salier_Amount Balance Amy_Price   Amy_Amount
1         80        120         40        70               90       20      0            0
3        110        600         490       0                0        0      60          200

Answer (score 0):

You could consider doing a pivot on the SQL side if you are using SQL Server (>2005).
The general syntax is:

```
SELECT
    [non-pivoted column], -- optional
    [additional non-pivoted columns], -- optional
    [first pivoted column],
    [additional pivoted columns]
FROM (
    SELECT query producing sql data for pivot
        -- select pivot columns as dimensions and
        -- value columns as measures from sql tables
) AS TableAlias
PIVOT
(
    <aggregation function>(column for aggregation or measure column) -- MIN,MAX,SUM,etc
    FOR [<column name containing values for pivot table columns>]
    IN (
        [first pivoted column], ..., [last pivoted column]
      )
) AS PivotTableAlias
ORDER BY clause -- optional
```

This would create the data in the format you are looking for and would make displaying straight forward.

Here is a nice tutorial:

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx

Comment: thx for reply 
i try pivot table, pivot only one aggregation but i need two column aggeregation etc.MIN(Price) for salesname([Mike]) MIN(Amount) for salesname([Mike])

Comment: In a stored procedure you could create the two two pivot tables and join them together by the cid.